# Measuring the length of a integer ( when interpreted as octal number)

Tags: php, numbers, octal

I need to know how many characters / numbers are in a number. Some of the numbers will have leading Zeros. After much reading I understand that if it has leading zeroes PHP translates this into an [octal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) number. But I need a way to void that and treat the number as a normal number. also I need to be able to print this to the screen with the leading zeros later.

Is there any straight forward work around for this?

I dont want the octal number. I want it to know is 00123 or at least 123 Not 83.

Idealy my desired output is `3` or `5` when counting the characters in the number. and is a number not a string to begin with

```
$a = 00123;
echo $a; // Returns 83
echo strlen((string)$a); // Returns 2
echo mb_strlen($a, "UTF-8"); //Returns 2

$b = "". 00123 ."";
echo strlen((string)$b);  //Returns 2
echo strlen(strval($b)); //Returns 2
```

Comment: If you just save them as a string? Or do you have to calculate with them?

Comment: I dont have to calculate anything with them. I just need to know how many characters are there to add more zeros until there are 8 characters.

Comment: Well then do as i said and save them as a string, so PHP will treat them as such and wont remove anything from them, like this: `$a = "00123";` and for counting the single numbers: `echo strlen(a);`. This should work, at least i see no reason why it shouldnt.

Comment: I'm sure some combination of `intval()`, `sprintf()` and `str_pad()` will solve your problem, but I'm not entirely sure what this problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [decoct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decoct.php) and [str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str_pad.php), like so. http://3v4l.org/TQgOq

```
<?php
echo str_pad(decoct(000123), 20, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

You may want to sanity check some of the incoming values though.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the whole answer, i dont like code in comments :3

```
$a = "00123";
echo $a; // Returns 00123
echo strlen($a); // Returns 5
echo mb_strlen($a, "UTF-8"); //Returns 5

$b = "". 00123 .""; //unnecessary
$b = $a; //easier
echo strlen((string)$b);  //both
echo strlen(strval($b)); //unnecessary
echo strlen($b); //returns 5
```